# Add several custom metadata Firebase Storage swift

Tags: ios, swift, firebase, storage

I'm trying to set multiple custom metadata to Firebase Storage on Swift

my code is the following:

```
let metadata = StorageMetadata()
        metadata.contentType = "image/jpg"
        metadata.customMetadata = ["lightVibrantColor" : "0"]
        metadata.customMetadata = ["imageWidth" : "\(updatedProfileImage.size.width)"]
        metadata.customMetadata = ["imageHeight" : "\(updatedProfileImage.size.height)"]
        metadata.customMetadata = ["darkMutedColor" : "0"]
```

However, only the last custom metadata is sent. I know that because when I change the last custom metadata for another one, that is the one that is being sent.

How can I add multiple custom metadata in order to send it to Firestore?

Comment: Firebase and Firestore both are different thing in first line you used Firebase and in last you used Firestore. Please clarify it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seems that you’re overriding the value. You need to change the code to:

```
let metadata = StorageMetadata()
metadata.contentType = "image/jpg"
metadata.customMetadata = ["lightVibrantColor" : "0",
"imageWidth" : "\(updatedProfileImage.size)",
"imageHeight" : "\(updatedProfileImage.size.height)",
"darkMutedColor" : "0"]
```

Answer (score 1):

From the [docs](https://firebase.google.com/docs/storage/ios/file-metadata#custom_metadata), the custom metadata can be set as

```
let metadata = [
  "customMetadata": [
    "location": "Yosemite, CA, USA",
    "activity": "Hiking"
  ]
]
```

Instead of replacing the value of metadata again and again, you should use a dictionary.

Answer (score 0):

First, you have to make instance of metadata... then, you add values to changeable property "customMetadata". After that, you connect that metadata to value that you have uploaded (in this case - image).

```
    let metadata = StorageMetadata()
    metadata.customMetadata = ["key" : "value", "key" : "value"]
    let uploadTask = childImage.putData(data, metadata: metadata){metadata, error in
        guard let metadata = metadata else {
            if error != nil {
                print("Error")
            }
            return
        }
    }
```

Then you can access your metadata and use it.

Comment: This is answer for Swift 5, xCode 11.